# Button, IInvokeProvider and Click

Tags: c#, wpf, events, ui-automation

I'm just trying to figure this one out. Why does the button `IInvokeProvider` call the click event without doing any explicit setting? What if I wanted to automate another method like `MouseEnter` or `MouseLeave`? And what makes it assume that when you call the `Invoke()` method it should do the `Click` event?

This is my code:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ButtonAutomationPeer buttonPeer = new ButtonAutomationPeer(button);
    IInvokeProvider invokeProvider = buttonPeer.GetPattern(PatternInterface.Invoke) as IInvokeProvider;
    invokeProvider.Invoke(); // this triggers button_Click handler
}

private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Button clicked!");
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "any explicit setting" here - what you you expect to happen instead?

Comment: As I mentioned, what if I wanted to automate another event?

Comment: UIAutomation is designed for a specific type of interaction - interacting with UI elements at level that's higher-level than input. So while clicking on a button with a mouse causes the button to be pressed and issue its command, and clicking on a list item causes it to be selected, UIAutomation sees these as two different things, even though they're both the result of mouse clicks: one is issuing a command (IInvokeProvider), the other is changing selection state (ISelectionItemProvider). If you want to work at the level of mouse input, then SendInput may be more appropriate than UIA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IInvokeProvider interface is part of the System.Windows.Automation family of namespaces also referred to as **WUIA (Windows User Interface Automation)**. WUIA is meant to support accessibility clients (screen readers and the like) to support for example blind users. The **IInvokeProvider.Invoke() method is invoking the default action** on the implementing UI element. In your case the default action on a button is the click event.

You will have to invoke Mouse events using a different interface.

Comment: Yup - ButtonAutomationPeer is really a support class for automation/accessibility (note that it's also used for things like automated testing or speech commanding in addition to accessibility). If you were to write your own custom button class that wasn't based on the existing button class, you'd need to provide your own MyButtonPeer that implements this interface so that these tools have a standard way to 'press' your button. 'Invoke' here represents anything that is command-like, so buttons and menu items both implement it.

Comment: Oh I did not know about those default actions. I'll search online to see what's the default action of each control. Thanks for the info!